# playwright python cant get the api pages using cookies

Tags: python-3.x, api, webautomation, playwright, playwright-python

I have two scripts in python:

login >> go to the website, login using login form and store the cookies into JSON file for later use

```
import json
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(slow_mo=50)
    context = browser.new_context(user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36')
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto('https://www.url.us/signin')
    try:
        page.wait_for_selector('#signInFormPage input[name="userName"]', state='visible')
        page.type('#signInFormPage input[name="userName"]', "aaa")
        page.type('#signInFormPage input[name="password"]', "aa")
        page.click('#userNamePasswordSignInButton')
        page.wait_for_timeout(3000)
        cookies = context.cookies()
        page.wait_for_timeout(10000)
        f = open('./cookies.json', 'w')
        f.write(json.dumps(cookies))
        page.close()
        context.close()
        browser.close()             
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in playwright script.")
        page.close()
        context.close()
        browser.close()
```

This script is working good.
The second script is get the stored cookies from file and print page source of the other pages for the same website:

```
import json
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=50)
    context = browser.new_context(user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36')
    page = context.new_page()
    cookie_file = open('./cookies.json')
    cookies = json.load(cookie_file)
    context.add_cookies(cookies)
    page.goto('https://www.url.us/Product/10aaa')
    try:
        page.wait_for_timeout(6000)
        print(page.content())
        page.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in playwright script.")
        page.close()
```

And this script is working good too.

But the issue is this website has API for some information that I want to pull out and that Infos are not available through the page source visible as the front end user. SO when I put the API link in the second link I receive the empty JSON page. Those API requests are using token value, but since I'm using the cookies for getting the page source I don't have a token. I use those scripts because it was the only way o get through the Cloudflare protection that this website has. Is there some way that I can for example use the requests module with the combination of playwright module? Or any other suggestions that can be helpful for this situation, how I can get the JSON page using cookies?

updated code using Persistent context:

1script:

```
import json
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch_persistent_context(r'C:\Users\test\Downloads\pyyy', headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('https://www.url.us/signin')
    try:
        page.wait_for_selector('#signInFormPage input[name="userName"]', state='visible')
        page.type('#signInFormPage input[name="userName"]', "aaaaa")
        page.type('#signInFormPage input[name="password"]', "aaaa")
        page.click('#userNamePasswordSignInButton')
        page.wait_for_timeout(3000)
        page.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in playwright script.")
        page.close()
```

2:

```
import json
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch_persistent_context(r'C:\Users\test\Downloads\pyyy', headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('https://www.url.us/Product/aaa')
    try:
        page.wait_for_timeout(6000)
        print(page.content())
        page.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in playwright script.")
        page.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saving and loading the cookies, I would launch a [Persistent context](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-browsertype?_highlight=persistent_context#browser_typelaunch_persistent_contextuser_data_dir-kwargs). This persistent context will preserve the information in the `user_data_dir`you provide.

Comment: Please check the updated code in my comment, I tried this but the second script gives me a page as non logged user, so did I do something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `page.wait_for_timeout(3000)` is enough to get the cookie there?

Comment: I put (13000) and still its the same